# Parse function time out management

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

In [Parse Cloud Code there is a response time limit of 15s](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-timeouts). We've been experiencing problems on certain requests that depend on external service requests.

If we have 4 promises, promise 1 & 2 create objects but if the request "runs out of time" on promise 3 we need to destroy whatever was created on the process. I'm cascading the error handling in a similar way as the following example:

```
var obj1, obj2, obj3;
query.find().then(function() {
    obj1 = new Parse.Object('Anything');
    return obj1.save();
}).then(function() {
    obj2 = new Parse.Object('Anything');
    return obj2.save();
}).then(function _success() {
    obj3 = new Parse.Object('Anything');
    return obj3.save();
}).then(function _success() {
    response.success();
}, function _error(err) {
   var errorPromises = [];
   if (obj1 != undefined) errorPromises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj1.id));
   if (obj2 != undefined) errorPromises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj2.id));
   if (obj3 != undefined) errorPromises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj3.id));

   Parse.Promise.when(errorPromises).then(function _success() {
        response.error();
   }, function _error() {
       response.error(err);
   });
});
```

The `deleteExternalStuff` function makes a `get` request on one of the object's id and then returns an `object.destroy()` promise.

My problem is that the `get` query works but the `destroy` promises inside the `deleteExternalStuff` are not deleting the objects from the database. Any suggestions on how to handle this case?

**EDIT:**

I've tested and whenever a timeout occurs, the error IS INDEED executed but the `destroy()` is what is not working just right.

**EDIT 2:** Added a similar structure for the `deleteExternalStuff` function

```
function deleteExternalStuff(objectId) {
    var query = Parse.Query('Another Object');
    query.equalTo('objXXX', objectId);
    return query.find().then(function _success(anotherBunchOfObjects) {
        var deletePromises = _.map(anotherBunchOfObjects, function(obj) {
            return obj.destroy();
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(deletePromises);
    }, function _error(error) {
        console.log(error);           // **ERROR LOG**
        return Parse.Promise.as();
    });
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

With further testing I added an error handler in `deleteExternalStuff` function and printed to log... Apparently the `**ERROR LOG**` prints the following: `{"code":124,"message":"Request timed out"}`

This makes me think that Parse doesn't permit the use of chained promises in error handling if you have already reached the timeout limit... :\

Suggestions for alternate solutions are appreciated.

Comment: To avoid the timeout issue, you could just make it a job.

Comment: can you post the `deleteExternalStuff` code?

Comment: Just added a third **edit** with more information on the error codes

Answer (score 0):

To make sure all objects are deleted before your request is finished, you will have to wait until all promises are resolved:

```
var promises = [];
if (obj1 != undefined) promises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj1.id));
if (obj2 != undefined) promises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj2.id));
if (obj3 != undefined) promises.push(deleteExternalStuff(obj3.id));
Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    response.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I actually had the `when`, sorry my bad... Just edited the question and also included the `deleteExternalStuff` function

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure the original error function waits until all promises are fulfilled since the error is a `timeout error`... If it were an `object not found` or something like that, the request would actually still have time remaining to execute queries, but I'm uncertain about Parse's behaviour in this scenario.